# Как создать vpn соединение на xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, vpn

Я пишу приложение для обмена сообщениями, есть шифрование между клиентами по Госту, хочу добавить в приложение подключение к серверу по `VPN`. На сколько я знаю требуется служба `ForegroundService` такая уже имеется и выполняет свои функции, так же отображается Уведомление в шторке, что служба работает. Не могу найти статью, где можно прочитать,  как реализовать подключение или библиотека какая есть. Подключение должно выглядеть, как в отведенных для такого  приложениях, в пример можно взять Psiphon. Ниже пример. В правом углу видно значок `VPN`. повторюсь Уведомление уже есть, служба работает стабильно и включается когда надо.

Адрес Сервера

L2TP/Ipsec PSK

Общий ключ Ipsec (есть)

Имя пользователя и пароль имеются

Это те данные которые требуются ввести для подключение к серверу
[image: Psiphon]
Настройки клиента
[image: настройки]
Так выглядит готовый клиент
[image: Клиент]

Comment: На разных андройдах разные возможности по подключению VPN туннелей, список поддерживаемых протоколов и т.д. Я бы не рекомендовал в одно приложение интегрировать все подряд. Для VPN есть специализированные клиенты. Например у нас на работе используется Cisco AnyConnect, и оно не совместимо со штатными VPN клиентами, где-то используется WireGuard, и так далее. Всё существующее вы даже технически не сможете реализовать, я бы не советовал заморачиваться. Суть VPN не только в значке [VPN] на экране. Смысл реализовывать свой VPN-клиент имеет только тогда, когда у вас есть свой публичный VPN-сервер.

Comment: @aepot, в этом вся суть , у мень есть сервер , на котором настроен VPN есть клиенты, которым выдается пул адресов. Есть параметры которые я ввожу у себя на телефоне 
Адрес сервера, тип подключения, юзер , пароль, и ключ шифрования Ipsec

Comment: @aepot,  Я хочу что бы приложение вводило эти данные за меня, я обновлю вопрос и добавлю картинку

Comment: Ну тогда расскажите, что за VPN - PPTP, L2TP, WireGuard, тип авторизации, шифрования и т.д., отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: @aepot, Вопрос был отредактирован

Comment: Дальше уже вам спецы по андройдам/Xamarin только смогут подсказать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56863899/12888024 https://stackoverflow.com/q/7913695/12888024 https://stackoverflow.com/q/49786946/12888024